# Creating new processes using node js does not have pid

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am following the example presented [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001808/ch03.html#using_multiple_processors) 
to create a server that would run on multiple cores.I get the following error:

```
 created worker: undefined
 created worker: undefined
 created worker: undefined
 created worker: undefined

workers[m.process].lastCb=new Date().getTime();
                                 ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'lastCb' of undefined
at Worker.<anonymous> (/home/anr/Desktop/node js/clustering2.js:56:29)
at Worker.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:345:11)
```

This is my code:

```
 var cluster=require('cluster');
 var os=require('os');
 var http=require('http');
 var numCores=os.cpus().length;

 var rsswarn=(50*1024*1024),
     heapWarn=(50*1024*1024);
 var workers={};

if(cluster.isMaster)
{
 for(var i=0;i<numCores;i+=1)
 {
    createWorker();
 }  

 setInterval(function killWorkers(){
    var time=new Date().getTime();
    for(pid in workers)
    {
        if(workers.hasOwnProperty(pid) && workers[pid].lastCb+5000<time)
        {
            console.log('Long running process '+pid+ ' killed');
            workers[pid].worker.kill();
            delete workers[pid];
            createWorker();
        }
    }
   },1000);
}

else
{
    http.Server(function makeServer(req,res){
if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) === 4) {
  console.log('Stopped ' + process.pid + ' from ever finishing');
  while(true) { continue; }
}
res.writeHead(200);
res.end('hello world from '  + process.pid + '\n');
}).listen(8000);
//Report stats once a second
setInterval(function report(){
process.send({cmd: "reportMem", memory: process.memoryUsage(), process: process.pid});
}, 1000);
}

  function createWorker()
 {
   var worker=cluster.fork();
   console.log('created worker: '+worker.pid);
   workers[worker.pid]={worker:worker,lastCb:(new Date().getTime()-1000)};
   worker.on('message',function(m){
    if(m.cmd==='reportMem')
    {
        workers[m.process].lastCb=new Date().getTime();
        if(m.memory.rss>rssWarn)
        {
            console.log('worker thread '+m.process+' taking too much memory');
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the pid in `worker.process.pid`. Either the example has a typo, or this has changed for newer versions of `node.js`.

```
// This works:
console.log('created worker: ' + worker.process.pid);
```

Reference: [worker.process](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_process) and [ChildProcess.pid](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_pid)

After changing all `worker.pid` to `worker.process.pid` you will also notice there is a typo with the variable `rsswarn` which is later called as `rssWarn`

After fixing these two things, your code should work.

Have fun!

Comment: Found it,was adding elements using `worker.pid` that should explain the error,also I noticed that I forgot to pass any arguments to the callback function when creating the server.

Comment: If you are using Linux - try with the tool called "htop". Then use F4 to filter "node" processes.